# using type punning to decompose object into words

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

Take a look at the following code which decompose an object into words in order to write the (word-aligned) object to memory using API which accepts only a word:

```
void func(some_type obj /*obj is word aligned*/, unsigned int size_of_obj_in_words)
{
    union punning{
        unsigned char bytes[4]; /* assume 4 bytes in word in my system */
        uint32_t      word;
    };
    union punning pun;
    unsigned char *legal_aliasing_by_char_pointer;
    for (int i=0; i < size_of_obj_in_words; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            legal_aliasing_by_char_pointer = (unsigned char *)&obj + j + i*4;
            pun.byte[j] = *legal_aliasing_by_char_pointer;
        }
        /* finally, using word aliasing to decompose object to words */
        /* endianity is not important */
        write_word_to_hw_by_word(pun.word)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to perform it in a c standard conforming way, so that strict aliasing rules won't be violated. Is that code achieve that goal?

Comment: I would add `static_assert(sizeof(uitn32_t) == 4 && CHAR_BIT == 8, "")` `i < size_of_obj_in_words` - your algorithm may behave strange for size greater then `INT_MAX`.

Comment: You may use "-Wstrict-aliasing" warning option (supported by GCC) - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @KamilCuk well there is some redundancy there, your two conditions imply each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks OK but you can simplify a lot:

```
void func(some_type obj)
{
    uint32_t word;

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof obj / sizeof word; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&word, (char *)&obj + i * sizeof word, sizeof word);
        write_word(word);
    }
}
```

The alignment of `obj` doesn't matter.  Also you don't need to pass the size since `sizeof` does the job.

I suspect it would perform better if you change the function to accept the address of the object, in which case you might want to pass an array length too.

Comment: is that conforming to strict aliasing? I always thought union type punning is the only way to do that.

Comment: @user2162550 Character types are an exception in strict aliasing rules, and `memcpy` is defined to copy characters. So yes, it is conforming.

Comment: Even easier is to increment i by `sizeof word`. And use `size_t` for counter.

Comment: @user2162550 memcpy never violates strict aliasing. The "effective type" will become that of the destination. However, this involves a copying operations which comes with execution overhead.

Comment: @Lundin ... the *declared* type of the destination if any, otherwise the effective type of the source...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah but that only applies in case of heap allocation etc so it isn't relevant here.

Comment: @Lundin Well, because you were missing the word "here" :d

Comment: @Lundin the abstract machine has a copy operation, the real machine probably doesn't

Comment: @M.M It seems as if they are writing to hardware though, in which case the last write operation will be volatile-qualified and then the compiler won't be able to optimize your extra memcpy.

Comment: @Lundin assuming that's a function taking argument by value (as opposed to some weird macro), that doesn't matter, the compiler can compile the code as reading 4 bytes from the source into whatever register or stack location is used to pass the value to the function

Comment: Yeah well, the OP's code is on the pseudo code side. If it is a direct register access, then the intermediate memcpy would be inefficient. Similar if it is a function with a register access visible in the same translation unit: then the compiler could inline it.

Comment: @Lundin: Heap allocations are cited as an example of objects with no declared type, but the Standard doesn't say that there are no others.  It would be unworkable to say that objects which are declared in one compilation unit but accessed via pointers in another to be treated within that latter unit as objects with declared types, but unfortunately the Standard completely fails to specify when it is or is not necessary to recognize objects as having declared types.

Comment: @supercat Memory-mapped hardware registers would be another such case, if they are only accessed indirectly through pointers and not declared as variables anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin: Memory-mapped registers should be declared `volatile`, and are a separate issue.  More important are situations like the one in Defect Report #028, whose response's nonsensical rationale formed the basis of the Effective Type rules, which can't even handle the scenario in DR #028.

Comment: @supercat Memory-mapped registers don't get an effective type until you write to them however, even if `volatile` will come in to save the day from strict aliasing optimizations. And you are preaching to the choir; I think the effective type/strict aliasing rules are to be regarded as a language defect. They are much too complex and far too abused by compiler optimizers. It is a perfectly reasonable to want to for example de-serialize a byte array by accessing it through a `*(uint32_t*)` access. However, I'm not sure the language was much better before these rules either.

Comment: @Lundin: The C89 aliasing rules would have been workable [albeit not ideal] with a couple of slight tweaks: "an object *which is accessed or addressed via* a given type may only be accessed *in conflicting fashion* by an lvalue which *is, after such access, derived from* one of the following types".  The C99 notion of Effective Type adds nothing but confusion.  Apply those tweaks, and recognize that storage is throughout its lifetime occupied by every object of every type that will fit, but there is no blanket permission to access structs or unions via member types, ...

Comment: ...and the correct answer to DR #028 (have you read it yet?) would be obvious.  Given `p1 = &myUnion.m1; *p1 = whatever; p2 = &myUnion.m2; return *p2;`, after the write to `*p1`, the lvalue `myUnion` would be expected to identify that storage, and since `p2` would be drived from `myUnion`, it would be allowed to access the storage from `myUnion`.  But if the code were p1 = &myUnion.m1; p2 = &myUnion.m2; *p1 = whatever; return *p2;`, `p2` would not be derived from `p1` nor from anything that would be allowed to alias `p1`; the latter example would match the situation of DR #028.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the type is large, perhaps you should pass it in by pointer instead.

If (and only if) the struct is already properly aligned like you say, you could cast the pointer to an union of the struct and array of `uint32_t`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct some_type {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} some_type;

void write_word_to_hw_by_word(uint32_t word);

void func(some_type *obj)
{
    union punning {
        uint32_t words[sizeof (some_type) / sizeof (uint32_t)];
        some_type obj;
    } *pun_ptr;

    pun_ptr = (union punning *)obj;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof (some_type) / sizeof (uint32_t); i++)
    {
        write_word_to_hw_by_word(pun_ptr->words[i]);
    }
}
```

Here we're using the lvalue expression `*pun_ptr` to access the words in `obj` by relying [C11 6.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7):

> 7. An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
>    - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>    - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>    - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>    - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>    - **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or**
>    - a character type.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe overthinking a bit. The following code doesn't violate strict aliasing rules.

```
void func(void *obj, size_t size_of_obj) // Passing address and size of object
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_of_obj; i += sizeof(word_type))
    {
        word_type word;
        memcpy(&word, obj, sizeof(word_type));
        write_word_to_hw_by_word(word);
        obj = (char *)obj + sizeof(word_type);
    }
}
```

It is also independent of the type of the object and does not make any large stack allocation.

Comment: When targeting an ARM with gcc 8.2, if `write_word_to_hw_by_word` were simply a volatile store, that code would likely be at least an order of magnitude slower than what could be obtained using the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect.

Comment: @supercat Probably true. But isn't the whole idea of strict-aliasing about speeding up code that _does not_ alias? So I can imagine that you might want to write some code that behaves predictably (albeit slower) despite strict-aliasing so that the compiler is able to better optimize your whole code-base.

Comment: Most of the performance advantages that could be reaped by aliasing assumptions do not require that compilers be anywhere near as aggressive as clang and gcc.  Compilers like icc will have no problem noticing that if one e.g. passes the address of a `float` to a function which takes a `void*` and it converts it to `uint32_t*`, such a function may affect the value of `float` objects, while assuming that `float` values could be cached across such a function if not given the address of a `float`.  The clang/gcc abstraction model offers little marginal benefit in most cases.

Comment: @supercat It is really unfortunate that toolchains with the kind of ubiquity that clang & gcc enjoy have overdone this in such an irresponsible manner. In their defense, the standard should have been clearer as well. As developers hoping to write portable code, (as I routinely do, that has to compile with both gcc and other toolchains) all we can do is either disable strict aliasing or try to find possibly inelegant/inefficient workarounds that work in all cases.

Comment: The maintainers of clang and gcc will continue to find new ways to break programs unless or until programmers stop appeasing them. and it is widely recognized that (1) the Standard deliberately allows implementations intended for specialized purposes to behave in ways unsuitable for any other, and (2) the full-optimizations-enabled dialect of clang and gcc may be suitable for a few specialized purposes, but is unsuitable for most others.  The authors expected Quality of Implementation issues to be resolved by the marketplace, which works if implementers need to respect customers to get paid.

Comment: The real problem is that clang and gcc have adopted, and become very highly invested in, an abstraction model that was never close to fitting the language the Standard was written to describe, but comes tantalizingly close to fitting the language it actually defines, and they regard any differences between the Standard and that model as defects in the Standard.  The only resolution is to recognize the existence of a high-level-only dialect which abandons all pretense of supporting low-level programming, and a separate low-level dialect which abandons efforts to fit the clang/gcc model.

Comment: A low-level dialect which made no effort to fit the clang/gcc model could still allow must *useful* aliasing optimizations, as well as many that aren't possible with the current Standard nor the clang/gcc adaptation of it, and the combined complexity of both dialects could be far lower than the complexity that would be necessary to have one dialect fit both purposes without new syntactic constructs.

Comment: @supercat As a user of the language, I frankly can't care less which way I need to implement things as long as there is one unambiguous approach that works everywhere, even if I don't like it and it breaks legacy code. I can even re-write legacy code, if I'm given proper warning while compiling. If not, I can always use an older standard. What happens with different 'dialects' is that for normal users, it becomes a mess to figure out which way to implement something, especially when it is not known in advance which platforms will have to be supported in the future.

Comment: We work a lot on proprietary protocol stacks, which need to (cross-) compile on various 8, 16 and 32 bit embedded platforms on various toolchains and on x86_64 for good measure. Our code, obviously involves a lot of memory manipulation and with strict-aliasing, it's utter mayhem. This is supposed to be what C is good at! IMHO the committee should step up and specify things a bit more clearly instead of leaving them open ended, at least in the next revision of the standard.

Comment: Just about every compiler that is suitable for low-level programming includes a mode which effectively augments the Standard with "In cases where parts of the Standard and the platform's documentation describe the behavior of some action, but some other part would characterize it as invoking UB, give priority to the former", and I expect the Committee expected implementations to apply that principle in cases where their customers would find it useful without regard for whether the Standard required it.  Quality compilers should be able to generate decent code even in such a mode.

Comment: Whether or not gcc and later clang should have ever adopted an abstraction model that is fundamentally incompatible with the language the Standard was written to describe, the fact remains that they have done so.  I can't imagine them ever allowing the Standard to fully describe a language suitable for low-level programming unless it *also* recognizes the legitimacy of a dialect based on the clang/gcc abstraction model.  On the other hand, having clang/gcc process a dialect that characterizes constructs that don't fit the clang/gcc model as UB would be better than having them process...

Comment: ...a dialect where such constructs have defined behavior but aren't actually processed reliably.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197998/discussion-between-supercat-and-th33lf).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that matters is the actual type of "some_type" and its members. Since it is not likely an array of `uint32_t`, then you'll have to do some trick to dodge strict aliasing. (As already noted, you should probably pass the struct as a pointer, but it doesn't change anything in regards to aliasing.)

Easiest way:

```
void func(some_type obj /*obj is word aligned*/, size_t size_of_obj_in_words)
{
  _Static_assert( (_Alignof(some_type) % _Alignof(uint32_t) )==0 , "Incorrect alignment");

  typedef union 
  {
    some_type  st;
    uint32_t   word[sizeof(some_type) / sizeof(uint32_t)];
  } pun_intended_t;

  pun_intended_t* pi = (pun_intended_t*) &obj;
  for(size_t i=0; i<size_of_obj_in_words; i++)
  {
    write_word_to_hw_by_word(pi->word[i]);
  }
}
```

This involves no intermediate copy buffer. Which is an advantage since `write_word_to_hw_by_word` probably involves a `volatile`-qualified access and it is probably(?) located in another translation unit, so the compiler isn't likely able to optimize away an intermediate `memcpy` to a temporary buffer.

Why the above works:

C17 6.7.2.1/16

> A pointer to a
>   union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members and vice versa.

And the exception from strict aliasing C17 6.5/7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:
>   /--/
>   - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members

Comment: Doesn't this cause potential unaligned access unless every constituent of some_type is of sizeof(uint32_t)?

Comment: @th33lf It shouldn't, but if so it would copy padding bytes along with the data. I used `_Alignof` in the assert mostly as self-documenting code, could as well have been `sizeof`. If the type isn't an even multiple of `uint32_t` then the algorithm doesn't make sense in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The question of whether to support various constructs is a Quality of Implementation issue, outside the jurisdiction of the Standard.  Quality implementations which are designed and configured for various tasks will uphold the Spirit of C principle "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done" in a manner appropriate for those tasks.

Unless one is stuck having to perform some task using an implementation or configuration that isn't particularly suitable, but is the best available, one should target implementation or configuration that allows one to write straightforward code, and then write straightforward code for it.

Neither clang nor gcc correctly handle all of the corner cases defined by the Standard when configured for `-fstrict-aliasing`, and trying to find ways of exploiting corner cases of the Standard to do things that could not be done effectively otherwise is a fool's errand.  The Standard makes no effort to require that all implementations be suitable for purposes requiring low-level semantics, and it supports what look like low-level semantics only for the purposes of accommodating code that only needs to do high level things.  If you need to do low-level things, write code in such a way that a compiler which makes any reasonable effort to support low-level semantics would have no trouble doing so, without worrying about whether the Standard would mandate support even by compilers that aren't intended for tasks requiring low-level semantics.